# How to fire an event after successful authentication with JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have a Laravel version 6 application. I use [JWT package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for authentication.

The routes defined like this:

```
// route/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
     Route::apiResources([
        'genders' => 'API\GenderController'
    ]);
});
```

Inside the controllers I have 5 functions `index`, `store`, `show`, `update` and `destroy`.

I need to set the locale for the current user before running any code inside these functions, something like this:

```
public function index()
{
     $locale = request()->user()->lang;    
     app()->setLocale($locale);
     // Rest of the function
}
```

My controller class extends a `BaseController` class. As the Restful API is state less I need to set the locale each time the user send a API request. Now the question is that where is the best place to do it and how can I do it?

I tried to do it inside the constructor of the BaseController but it seems the `middleware('auth:api')` has not yet checked the token in constructor.

The other option is to set the locale inside a authentication event handler. I found a list of JWT package events [here](https://medium.com/@3lpsy/apis-and-laravel-part-2-jwt-tymon-3e7f365af81c):

```
// fired when the token could not be found in the request
Event::listen('tymon.jwt.absent');

// fired when the token has expired
Event::listen('tymon.jwt.expired');

// fired when the token is found to be invalid
Event::listen('tymon.jwt.invalid');

// fired if the user could not be found (shouldn't really happen)
Event::listen('tymon.jwt.user_not_found');

// fired when the token is valid (User is passed along with event)
Event::listen('tymon.jwt.valid');
```

If someone could help me to define a handler for `tymon.jwt.valid` I would be appreciated. Or even if you have some other solution for running an event before execution of `index`, `store`, `show`, `update` and `destroy` functions.

Comment: what is wrong with a middleware?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with middleware. Just it checks the token after creating an instance of the destination class. If I run the code inside the `index` function the user is accessible because the check is already done. But If I do it inside the constructor function the user is null and it shows the token has not yet checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a different way for accessing the current user inside the constructor class. While the `request()->user()` code returns null in constructor, `auth()->user()` return the current user even in the constructor.

```
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $locale = auth()->user()->lang;
        app()->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
```

Therefore I could set the locale in my `BaseController` class.

However, my question regarding working with JWT events is open. Also I would like to know more details about working with middleware as @patryk-karczmarczyk suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in the middleware. Just put middleware that authenticates user before the one that sets location.

Create your route class and register it in `App\Http\Kernel::$routeMiddleware`

Then use it like this:

```
// rouite/api.php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'locale']], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'genders' => 'API\GenderController'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: can you clarify your answer more?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware. Concept of the middlewares is that they are executed before your route, you can authorize user (which you do) inside middleware and then pass the request to next middleware or to the controller action itself.

Middlewares are chained, so they are invoked one by another, therefore if you first check authorization in next middlewares you will have authorized user inside you request.